# Flag if a row is duplicated an attach if it's the 1st, 2nd, etc duplicated row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I'd like to flag if a row is duplicated, and attach if it's the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc duplicated column in a Pandas DataFrame.

More visually, I'd like to go from:

| id | Country | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France | Paris |
| 2 | France | Paris |
| 3 | France | Lyon |
| 4 | France | Lyon |
| 5 | France | Lyon |

to

| id | Country | City | duplicated_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France | Paris | 1 |
| 2 | France | Paris | 1 |
| 3 | France | Lyon | 2 |
| 4 | France | Lyon | 2 |
| 5 | France | Lyon | 2 |

Note that id is not taken into account to see if the row is duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

First, if you have lots of columns that you need to compare, you can use:

```py
comparison_df = df.drop("id", axis=1)
df["duplicated_flag"] = (comparison_df != comparison_df.shift()).any(axis=1).cumsum()
```

We drop the columns that aren't needed in the comparison. Then, we check whether each row is equivalent to the one above it using `.shift()` and `.any()`. Finally, we read off the value of `duplicated_flag` using `.cumsum()`.

---

But, if you only have two columns to compare (or if for some reason you have lots of columns that you need to drop), you can find mismatched rows one at a time, and then use `.cumsum()` to get the value of `duplicated_flag` for each row. It's a bit more verbose so I'm not super happy with this option, but I'm leaving this here for completeness in case this suits your use case better:

```py
country_comparison = df["Country"].ne(df["Country"].shift())
city_comparison = df["City"].ne(df["City"].shift())
df["duplicated_flag"] = (country_comparison | city_comparison).cumsum()
print(df)
```

---

These output:

```py
     id    Country      City  duplicated_flag
0  1     France     Paris                   1
1  2     France     Paris                   1
2  3     France      Lyon                   2
3  4     France      Lyon                   2
4  5     France      Lyon                   2
```

Comment: The new better option doesn't return the output as the original one. It just enumerates the rows from 1 until n of rows.

Comment: Are you sure? They both work for me.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. Original one works fine though.

Comment: Are you using it on the DF in the question, or on data with more columns? You may need to update which columns you're dropping in `df.drop`.